# FabricJS toDataURL Multiplier Not Returning Correct Height/Scaling Correctly

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I have a FabricJS canvas that has to be converted to a PDF that matches the exact fractional inches for print production. Per other questions I have received, my printer is a large format printer and actually needs this/is capable to printing to the exact decimal as follows:

```
Width (Inches): 38.703111
Height (Inches): 25.999987
```

Since the requirements are a DPI of 300, I obtained the pixels by multiplying the width and height x 300 as follows:

```
38.703111 inches x 300 =  11610.9333 px
25.999987 inches x 300 = 7799.9961 px
```

With these measurements in hand, I created a FabricJS canvas that users could edit and then convert to an image (will need to figure out how to convert it to a PDF server side later/suspecting node.js with the pdfkit module).

Since it is not usable to have a 11610 x 7799px Canvas on a page, I set the size of the canvas as follows:

```
Width: 650px
Height: 436.6571863 (Orginal Height * New Width / Orginal Width = new height)
```

Here is what my Canvas looks like (HTML) and corresponding JavaScript code to render it:

```
<canvas id="c" width="650" height="436.6571863" style="border:1px solid"></canvas>

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {});
```

Users are able to edit the canvas and then convert it to an image, but this is the problem occurs. I attempt to scale the canvas via FabricJS' toDataURL method using a multiplier of **17.86297431**  (Original Width in Pixels / New Width in Pixels and Original Height in Pixels / New Height in Pixels both equal a multiplier of 17.86297431) as follows:

```
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({
        format: 'png',
        multiplier: 17.86297431
    })

document.write('<img src="' + dataURL + '"/>');
```

However, once it scales, the width of my outputted image appears correct at 11610, but the height is off at 7788 when it should be 7799. This output does not show fractions, but rather just the whole pixels when I inspect the element.

My question is, how can I get my FabricJS Canvas to properly scale up to the pixels (or inches) so I can have my PDF (converted from my PNG) in the correct dimensions? Is this an issue with pixel fractions not being respected/what can I do about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set NUM_FRACTION_DIGITS in fabric.js file
By default this value = 2, you can change it and set for example = 9

Now your multiplier = 9,0123456;
But for Fabric JS your multiplier = 9,012;

If your will set NUM_FRACTION_DIGITS = 9 you will get your multiplier = 9,0123456;

Here the proof link: http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html

That is what you need: NUM_FRACTION_DIGITS - Defines the number of fraction digits to use when serializing object values. You can use it to increase/decrease precision of such values like left, top, scaleX, scaleY, etc.

Comment: Where do you set this?  This is not a global variable... nor is it attached to the global static "fabric"

Comment: You can set it like this fabric.Object.NUM_FRACTION_DIGITS = 9, before creating a new fabric object. Refer this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/johndubya/mwx2hz54/26/

Answer (score 0):

You should not work with float dimensions, that is a bad idea. Why don't you use `Math.ceil` for your dimensions. This will make no visual difference and this is the approach usually used.
Also you could use the Zoomify alghoritm approach to determine your scale factor. You can start from the original dimensions and divide them by 2 until you get a value smaller than a maximum value defined by you, which you consider acceptable. That way your scale factor will be a power of 2.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: Decimals even as small .005 scale difference DO make a visual difference with large images (ie, 10,000 px)